# É correto criar uma variável dentro de um if?

Tags: php, if, psr

é correto criar uma variável dentro de um if ?

No código abaixo cria-se uma variável dentro do if, e evita-se usar duas vezes o mesmo filtro.

```
if($id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)):
    /* Código */
endif;
```

O que vocês acham da pratica dentro do IF?
Isso é contra alguma norma dos PSR's (`PHP Standards Recommendation`) ?

{Obrigado}

Comment: Qual seria a versão desse código sem o if? as vezes é últil outras não xD

Comment: Eu acho bom colocar a questão das PSR no título, pq o resto meramente depende de opinião. Se vai usar a informação, o estranho seria justamente não criar a variável. Ainda que no caso do `if` você poderia criar antes.

Comment: Se não fosse coitada das pessoas que usam `while($busca=mysql_fetch_array($sql))`

Comment: Acredito que seja válido, porém a certas coisas que você pode utilizar o `&&` ou `||` antes de criar duas condições em sequência, mas vai da solução a se resolver....

Comment: Não tem problema nenhum, vai da necessidade de se fazer isso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, o `if` não é um bom exemplo, pois você pode "criar" a variável uma vez só, mesmo fora:

```
$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)
if( $id ):
   /* Código que usa o $id, sem "criar" de novo */
endif;
```

Mas num `while` já complica, então vou usar isto como exemplo:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row[1]);
}
```

Neste caso, não só e correto, como é um [exemplo tirado do manual do PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php).

Já que no `while` não só é um caso comum, mas muitas vezes necessário, não vejo motivo pra não poder usar no `if`. No fim, a legibilidade é sempre o mais importante. E para isto, só depende do contexto onde você vai usar. No exemplo acima com certeza não houve ganho em separar as linhas.

Se tiver qualquer PSR dizendo o contrário, tem que consertar a PSR, em vez de complicar o código.

Comment: Acho que nesse caso(if) ainda se encaixe um ternario maroto ;)

Comment: @rray mas a premissa é ele usar o $id dentro do bloco do `if` depois né? Se eu botar um ternário lá, complica o reuso, se for em mais de um lugar.

Comment: Sim, pode ser criar a variável, porem em um caso que a variável só vai existir dentro do if essa opção não é valida. O if dessa forma me poupa ter de criar a variável dentro do if, pois a mesma já foi criada. Minha duvida mesmo é sobre esta de alguma forma errado, pois o Netbeans gera um alerta informando que foi acidental a criação da variável dentro do if!

Comment: "em um caso que a variável só vai existir dentro do if essa opção não é valida" Isso nao é verdade, veja http://ideone.com/cvzNmW - se criou dentro do teste do IF, ela é do escopo externo. Diferente de criar dentro do BLOCO do if.

Comment: @Bacco Falei errado, não quis dizer que ela não rodaria dentro do if, eu quis dizer que não faz sentido criar ela fora do if. Desculpa erro meu na hora de me expressar.

Comment: @jjdomroam De qq forma, é bom pra relembrarmos o escopo :) Estamos olhando um exemplo simples, se for um if complexo onde você cria a variável e faz operações com ela, chega a fazer sentido sim. Imagine isso: `if( ( $id = MegaCalculo() * 45.2 / Sqrt( 999999999) ) < AjusteSenoidalDoFatorX( 2347) )` Neste caso, fica interessante tirar o `$id = MegaCalculo() * 45.2 / Sqrt( 999999999 )` e deixar só `if( $id < AjusteSenoidalDoFatorX( 2347 ) )`, não? Como eu disse, o que manda é o contexto. Tem hora que é melhor de um jeito, tem hora que é melhor de outro. Vai da complexidade das expressões.

Comment: @Bacco Sim, faz sentido nesse caso criar a variável fora do if, ate mesmo no seu primeiro exemplo faz sentido tira ela do if se eu for usa-la em outros lugares fora dele. Minha duvida mesmo é por conta do meu NetBeans que gera um pequeno alerta falando que foi acidental a criação da variável, o que me passa a ideia que eu estaria fazendo algo errado!

Comment: @jjdomroam experimente usar `( )` pra deixar claro pra IDE que vc fez de proposito. Por exemplo: `if( ( $id = Funcao() ) ):` - nao sei se funciona no netbeans, mas talvez resolva. Se bem que eu nao sei o que é pior, o alerta ou os ( ) atrapalhando leitura.

Comment: @Bacco Funcionou perfeitamente :v, meu IDE não gera mais alerta na linha. Obrigado pela dica!

Comment: @Bacco Não atrapalha muito a leitura, agora fico na duvida mesmo se vale apenas incluir os () para o capricho do IDE.

Comment: @jjdomroam decisao complicada :) Veja se nao tem como desativar essa detecção específica nas opções. Nao conheço bem o netbeans

Comment: @Bacco Tem sim, já desativei, Obrigado!